How to insert a character to a TextField at cursor position?
I added an extra toolbar with easy to access arithmetic operators.
@State private var formulaText: String = ""

var body: some View {
    TextField("Formula", text: $formulaText)
        .keyboardType(.asciiCapable)
        .autocorrectionDisabled()
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .keyboard) {
                HStack(spacing: 5.0) {
                    toolbarButtonImage(systemName: "plus") { formulaText += "+" }
                    toolbarButtonImage(systemName: "minus") { formulaText += "-" }
                    toolbarButtonImage(systemName: "multiply") { formulaText += "×" }
                    toolbarButtonImage(systemName: "divide") { formulaText += "÷" }
                    toolbarButtonText(text: "(") { formulaText += "(" }
                    toolbarButtonText(text: ")") { formulaText += ")" }
                }
            }
        }
}

As the action suggests it will add the character at the end of the text. This works well, but breaks whenever the user puts the cursor somewhere else. Now the user would expect the character to be added at the cursor position, but I won't.
How can this be accomplished? How can you insert a character in a TextField at the cursor position?

I don't think SwiftUI supports this (yet). I'd just wrap a UITextView/UITextField or use SwiftUI-introspect.

It's weird that something so basic isn't included yet in SwiftUI. 5 years after it's release =)
